# How to logout in my own oauth2 clients

Tags: oauth-2.0

I creat OAuth 2.0 server and some clients , but I don't how to logout with SSO.when i click login after logout, i need no more username and password. I want to login 'really'. it's said a tricky problem in

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

So anybody can give me some idea to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for logout functionality

```
@Controller
public class RevokeTokenController {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/revoke-token", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authHeader != null) {
            try {
                String tokenValue = authHeader.replace("Bearer", "").trim();
                OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
                tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }           
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```